# Unable to save SVG to PDF using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I'm trying to download PDF with SVG content using jsPDF library, it is able to download the file, but there is no content inside it, it is empty PDF.

This is my code:

```
const downloadPDF = (goJSDiagram) => {
  const svg = goJSDiagram.makeSvg({scale: 1, background: "white"});
  const svgStr = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
  const pdfDoc = new jsPDF();
  pdfDoc.addSvgAsImage(svgStr, 0, 0, pdfDoc.internal.pageSize.width, pdfDoc.internal.pageSize.height)
  pdfDoc.save(props.model[0].cName?.split(" (")[0] + ".pdf");
}
```

When I do `console.log(svgStr)`, I can see the SVG XML string. What changes should I make to render the content inside PDF?

Comment: Are you sure `pdfDoc.internal.pageSize.width` or `...height` is returning a value or this value is > 0 ? You can try at least some fixes values to test it.

Comment: I tried values like pdfDoc.addSvgAsImage(svgStr, 0, 200, 500, 500); still the same

Comment: Have you used your step-through debugger to troubleshoot? If not, _why not?_

Comment: This has nothing to do with react

Comment: Yes, doing this in react project, I thought I would add react code, but it is not necessary, thanks!

Comment: I can see you found a way to work around it using a hack where you rasterize the vector image, but in case you try to debug this again it would be interesting to see what was the reason for this issue. It certainly seems like you are passing in the right props to the API, so have you checked that they all have the expected values (like, not all being 0)?
https://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-svg.html#%7EaddSvgAsImage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of searching, I found the right way to do this, though the content rendered is little blurred.

```
  const waitForImage = imgElem => new Promise(resolve => imgElem.complete ? resolve() : imgElem.onload = imgElem.onerror = resolve);

  const downloadPDF = async (goJSDiagram) => {
    const svg = goJSDiagram.makeSvg({scale: 1, background: "white"});
    const svgStr = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(svgStr);

    waitForImage(img)
      .then(_ => {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = 500;
        canvas.height = 500;
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, 500, 500);
        const pdfDoc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
        pdfDoc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1.0), 0, 200, 500, 500);
        pdfDoc.save(props.model[0].cName?.split(" (")[0] + ".pdf");
      });
  }
```

Comment: If you are rasterizing a vector image to then use it within a format that is a vector format at heart (pdf), then this is hardly the _right_ way, though it might be _one_ way of doing it ;-) The original approach _is_ the right way, but you would need to debug it a bit to figure out why it fails.

Comment: After looking at the JSPDF code, they too are rasterizing the SVG, which is a bit of a shame, to be honest. They could have gotten crystal clear vectors as well. Not sure why they went that route. Maybe the simplest/cheapest?

Answer (score 3):

I think I know what is going on after getting a good hint from [this Github issue](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/2998#issuecomment-1189082121):

> There's the issue that addSvgAsImage() is asynchronous

You are not awaiting the call to finish before calling save! That means you are trying to save before the SVG has started rendering to the PDF.

See the [quite simple code](https://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/modules_svg.js.html) in question:

```
  jsPDFAPI.addSvgAsImage = function(
  // ... bla bla
 return loadCanvg()
      .then(
        function(canvg) {
          return canvg.fromString(ctx, svg, options);
        },
        function() {
          return Promise.reject(new Error("Could not load canvg."));
        }
      )
      .then(function(instance) {
        return instance.render(options);
      })
      .then(function() {
        doc.addImage(
          canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0),
          x,
          y,
          w,
          h,
          compression,
          rotation
        );
      });
```

As you see, it is just a chain of Thenables. So you simply need to await the Promise, which means your code would look something like this in ES2015+:

```
const downloadPDF = async (goJSDiagram) => {
  const svg = goJSDiagram.makeSvg({scale: 1, background: "white"});
  const svgStr = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
  const pdfDoc = new jsPDF();
  await pdfDoc.addSvgAsImage(svgStr, 0, 0, pdfDoc.internal.pageSize.width, pdfDoc.internal.pageSize.height)
  pdfDoc.save(props.model[0].cName?.split(" (")[0] + ".pdf");
}
```

Comment: You are right, I need to await the Promise, but the image is not fitting correctly in the pdf even though the width and height changes are made

Answer (score 0):

```js
doc.addSvgAsImage(imgData, 20, 50, 17, 20 );
doc.save('filename');
```

`save()` method is executed earlier than `doc.addImage(...)`

It worked for me when I put doc.save() into small setTimeout().
The other solution would be to convert SVG to JPEG and use `addImage()` method instead of `addSvgAsImage()`.